# CBV using django-filter with django-table2

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-tables2

***I want to use django-table2 with django-filter.*** I done what django-table2 document said but form of django-filter didn't display in my template.

These are my codes:

```py
    # Views.py 
    from django_filters.views import FilterView
    import django_filters
    from django_tables2 import SingleTableView
    
    class MYFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ['field1', 'field2' ]
    
    class MyView(SingleTableView, FilterView):
         model = MyModel
         table_class = MyTable
         template_name = 'my_template.html'
         filterset_class = MYFilter
    
    # tables.py 
    import django_tables2 as tables
    class MyTable(tables.Table):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ("field1", "field2",)
    
    # my_template.html
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
    {% if filter %}
    <form method="get">
        {{ filter.form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    {% endif %}
    {% if table %}
    <div class="table-responsive">
        {% render_table table %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

***The table render correctly, but the form didn't render. What's wrong with my code?***

Comment: You use two baseclasses, so likely the `SingleTableView`, never calls the `super()` view of the `FilterView` to "inject" the `filter`.

Comment: So, what can I do to solve this problem? @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *method resolution order (MRO)* will put the filter view that low that it has no impact, indeed:

```
>>> MyView.__mro__
(<class 'MyView'>,
 <class 'django_tables2.views.SingleTableView'>,
 <class 'django_tables2.views.SingleTableMixin'>,
 <class 'django_tables2.views.TableMixinBase'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.ListView'>,
 <class 'django_filters.views.FilterView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.BaseListView'>,
 <class 'django_filters.views.BaseFilterView'>,
 <class 'django_filters.views.FilterMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

This is important since the `BaseFilterView` will override the `get` method, but since the `BaseListView` appears first in the MRO, it will not have any impact. If we swap the parents, so:

```
class MyView(FilterView, SingleTableView):
    # …
```

the mro is:

```
>>> MyView.__mro__
(<class 'MyView'>,
 <class 'django_filters.views.FilterView'>,
 <class 'django_tables2.views.SingleTableView'>,
 <class 'django_tables2.views.SingleTableMixin'>,
 <class 'django_tables2.views.TableMixinBase'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.ListView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>,
 <class 'django_filters.views.BaseFilterView'>,
 <class 'django_filters.views.FilterMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.BaseListView'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>,
 <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

and thus the `get` logic of the `BaseFilterView` will be used.

Answer (score 1):

As @willem-van-onsem said you use two `baseclasses`. So you must change this line:

```
class MyView(SingleTableView, FilterView):
```

to this:

```
class MyView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
```

You can see `django-table2` document for use `django-filter` in this [link](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/filtering.html).